# Working with sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session

Im new to PHP, I need someone to walk me through working with sessions. I mean, how do you save and retrieve variables.

How can I derive such variables?

How can I pass them from one page to another?

ps: I am basically asking for a tutorial on sessions.

Comment: A simple Google search will give you tons of tutorials and information about this.

Answer (score 3):

The PHP manual has a [basic sessions usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) tutorial.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
```

Session variables persist between pages (as long as you call `session_start()` on each one), you don't have to do anything to get them to pass.

Comment: @world, I think it doesn't make sense to upvote answers and downvote the question that caused the answer to get an upvote.

Comment: @Irwin It's entirely possible to have a good answer to a bad question. Why are you commenting on this nine months after it got closed?

Comment: I comment because I can.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) tutorial, just to begin. It's very clear and it contains very good examples.

Answer (score 0):

To start a session use `session_start();` at the top of your page.

To make a session variable:

```
$myvariable = 1;
$_SESSION['variable'] = $myvariable;
```

Now create another page that has `session_start();` at the top

And print the session variable, checking if it exists,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['variable'])){

echo $_SESSION['variable'];

//which should print '1';

}
```

To unset a session use destroy_session();

A great and simple tutorial that I used to learn PHP sessions can be found [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

I hope this helps.

Thanks

Chris